# How to implement wifi direct like a super beam?

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifimanager, wifip2p

I want to implement Wifi direct as follows:

1. From Device:  Enabling Wifi Direct
2. Generate Wifi direct id using barcode scanner
3. Receiver needs to scan the barcode and connect to "To Device" and transfer data from "From Device"

Can you suggest how to get wifi direct id in barcodescanner later which can be used for connecting in "To Device" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to answer my Question after spending more effort around this.

Basic steps I have followed as below:

1. Enable Wifi Direct
2. Create a group and request group info.
3. Group info consists of SSID and Passphrase

Through the above step 3, Any Wifi support device can access or connect to this Network.

In my scenario, I have read this ssid and password from the source device through barcode scanner and added new wifi network programatically to connect to this network.

See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html) more information on wifi direct.

Answer (score 1):

refer this link for Wifi Direct.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html
http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html

Comment: yes, I have gone through it. But in my scenario, I need to generate one pin in the form of barcode. Here what needs to be supplied to barcode generator ?